# How to solve a differential equation system involving complex conjugates?

Tags: differential-equations

Consider the following system of differential equations

```
sys = {y'[t] == g*z[t], z'[t] == g*y[t], y[0] == y0, z[0] == z0};
```

which we can solve

```
DSolve[sys, {y, z}, t]
```

Now, what if the system has complex conjugates involved?

```
sys2 = {y'[t] == g*Conjugate[z[t]], z'[t] == g*Conjugate[y[t]], y[0] == y0, z[0] == z0};
```

In this case

```
DSolve[sys2, {y, z}, t]
```

will fail.

So my question is: How can I solve the system `sys2`?
Also more general remarks about solving systems, where complex conjugates are involved are welcome.

P.S: We can assume g real and positive here, if that helps finding the answer.

Comment: isn't the standard method to solve the real part of the ode and the complex part (separately) then add solutions? i.e. if the solution to the real part is `solR` and the solution to the complex part is `solX` then the solution is `solR+  I * solX`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 DSolve[{y1'[t] == g*z1[t], y2'[t] == -g*z2[t], z1'[t] == g*y1[t], 
  z2'[t] == -g*y2[t], y1[0] == y01, y2[0] == y02, z1[0] == z01, 
  z2[0] == z02}, {y1[t], y2[t], z1[t], z2[t]}, t]



(*   {{y1[t] -> 1/2 E^(-g t) (y01 + E^(2 g t) y01 - z01 + E^(2 g t) z01), 
      z1[t] -> 1/2 E^(-g t) (-y01 + E^(2 g t) y01 + z01 + E^(2 g t) z01), 
      y2[t] -> 1/2 E^(-g t) (y02 + E^(2 g t) y02 + z02 - E^(2 g t) z02), 
      z2[t] -> -(1/2)
          E^(-g t) (-y02 + E^(2 g t) y02 - z02 - E^(2 g t) z02)}}  *)
```

Have fun!